# How to handle expiration of OAuth access_token using Asana node client?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, asana, asana-connect

Using Asana's NodeJS module (https://github.com/Asana/node-asana) with OAuth, how should I handle expiration of the access_token? Does the client provide some mechanism that I should use to detect this? Does it provide something I should use to get a new access_token using the refresh_token? I haven't been able to find any discussion of the refresh_token in the documentation.

---

I've registered my app and I'm able to successfully get credentials using the Client.app.accessTokenFromCode API. Something like this:

```
function handleOauthCallback(req, res) {
    var client = Asana.Client.create({
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        redirectUri: computeRedirectUrl(req)
    });
    client.app.accessTokenFromCode(req.query.code).then(function(credentials) {
        // store credentials
    }
}
```

I'm storing the entire credentials object that comes back from this call and later creating a client using those credentials. Something like this:

```
var client = Asana.Client.create({
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirectUri: computeRedirectUrl(req)
});
var storedCredentials = getStoredCredentials();
client.useOauth({ credentials : storedCredentials });
```

Now that I've got a client that's initialized with the credentials I got back from Asana (which includes an access_token and refresh_token), how should I handle expiration of the access_token? Do I need to check whether it's still valid myself and ask for a new token using the refresh token? Or will the client handle it for me automatically? If the client handles it, how do I find out when it gets a new access token?

### Update

Reading the code, it appears that the client will try to use the refresh token if the access token is no longer valid. But I don't see any kind of notification that I can hook into to find out that there's a new access token. Is there a recommended strategy to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I work at Asana). This is a great question, and we should add answers to the documentation.

The `dispatcher` can be passed an option called `handleUnauthorized` which is a callback to run when it gets a 401 (which if you started with good credentials should only happen when your token expires). It's [documented in the code](https://github.com/Asana/node-asana/blob/master/lib/dispatcher.js).

The default behavior of this option is to call `Dispatcher.maybeReauthorize`, which will make the backend request to get a new access token if it has a refresh token.

So if you just want the dispatcher to transparently refresh the access token, you don't need to do anything, it should "just work"! But if you want to intercept this process, you can pass `handleUnauthorized` in the dispatch options and then do whatever you want, possibly including calling the default method.

If you want to see the new access token, well .. the `Authenticator` class is abstract and we haven't provided a robust way to *extract* credentials from it; maybe we can add that. If you really need this, you could assume it's the oauth flavor with something like:

```
handleUnauthorized: function() {
  return Dispatcher.maybeReauthorize.call(dispatcher).then(
      function(reauthorized) {
        if (reauthorized) {
          onCredentials(dispatcher.authenticator.credentials);
        }
        return reauthorized;
      });
}
```

This isn't beautiful, but it should work for you. Just be aware we may evolve this interface a bit over time and you may have to tweak it in the future.

Comment: About making the new access_token available to clients: If we can't get the new token, it means we'll have to keep creating our clients with an expired access_token. So the client will end up needing to get a new token for every request.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How many clients are you making? Ideally you just make one and share/re-use it; it's not designed to be efficient if a new one is created for each request. But I see that if you're on the server, you want to store off the credential perhaps for a future request (where you may be making a new client). In that case, yes you should probably implement something like the above so you can intercept and store a new access token.

Comment: My server is stateless, so I make a new client object for every request to my server. I verified this morning, that this is working like a charm. My access token expired over the weekend, and this code let me detect and capture the new token. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea how to do this if we're not using the node package?